Rewriting Pine Script session function version 4 to 5
The session.ispremarket function is not working as it had in version 4 of Pine Script.  The following code below worked just fine in version 4 and I can't find what has changed in the Session Function that is causing the problem.
How can I make an adjustment for this function to work in version 5?
//@version=4

//Find the Premarket Open price at 4am
var float premarketOpen = na
isFirstPremarketBar = session.ispremarket and not session.ispremarket[1]

if isFirstPremarketBar
    premarketOpen := open

//Find Yesterday's Postmarket Close price at 8pm
var float postmarketClose = na
isLastPostmarketBar = session.ispostmarket[1] and not session.ispremarket

if isLastPostmarketBar
    postmarketClose := close


This works. You can use the session.isfirstbar and session.islastbar variables
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
var float premarketOpen = na

isFirstPre = session.isfirstbar and session.ispremarket

if isFirstPre
    premarketOpen := open

var float postmarketClose = na
isLastPost = session.islastbar and session.ispostmarket

if isLastPost
    postmarketClose := close

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index,high,str.tostring(premarketOpen,format.mintick) + '\n' + str.tostring(postmarketClose,format.mintick),textcolor=color.white)

